# making sense of a locally closed set being defined over k

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Say that $V$ is an affine variety defined over $k$ and that $W$ is a locally closed subset of $V$. Is there some sufficient condition for $W$ to have a canonical $k$-structure?

Comment: It's necessary to explain what version of language in affine algebraic geometry is being used here.   Historically there was a key distinction between being defined over $k$ and being $k$-closed.   Meanwhile the notions of $k$-structure and variety have evolved.   See for instance section AG.12 of Borel's 1969 W.A. Benjamin lecture notes, reproduced for the most part in the second edition GTM published by Springer in 1991.   There he tried to combine ideas from scheme theory with the older language of Weil and others concerning fields of definition.

Comment: Thank you for your help, could I please ask a question. Let's say that $W$ was the intersection of a set which was defined over $k$ and the complement of a $k$-closed set. Would I be right in thinking that that would be enough for it to have a canonical $k$-structure?

Comment: I'm not sure what it means to have a canonical $k$-structure, but I'm pointing out the problem one has over an impferfect field $k$.   For instance, take $V$ to be affine $n$-space over $k$, with $W$ a $k$-closed subset that isn't defined over $k$.   What are you asking about $W$?

Comment: If $W$ is actually defined over $k$, then there is an obvious way to put a $k$-structure on $\overline{k}[W]$. Whereas if it is merely $k$-closed it seems as though it's not that obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that $W$ has a canonical $k$-variety structure without our imposing any additional assumptions.

The closure $\overline{W}$ has a canonical affine $k$-variety structure since it is a closed subset of $V$. By virtue of being locally closed, $W$ is open in $\overline{W}$. Therefore, $W$ has the structure of an open subvariety of $\overline{W}$.

In general, a locally closed subset of an affine variety is called a quasi-affine variety.